# document sharing on sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, document-library

So I've been reading (and checking on my vm) that SharePoint 2013 has a built in capability to share documents with users inside and outside your organization without breaking the permission inheritance. I know this can be achieved using the javascript function.

Can this be done using the SharePoint C# api?

Thanks, and happy coding